# How to change a link to active state using an onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a common side navigation bar where I have linked several pages to it. I have included it to all the pages using the below php include statement.

`<?php include '../php/playersidenav.php';?>`

The sidenavigation is as follows.

```html
<div class="column sidenav">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="../images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
        <h1 style="color:white;float:right;padding-top:7%">Hello John!</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="normal" href="news.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">NEWS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="schedule.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">SCHEDULE</a>
    <a class="normal" href="partners.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">PARTNERS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="coaches.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">COACHES</a>
    <a class="normal" href="tournaments.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">TOURNAMENTS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="events.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">EVENTS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="shops.php" onclick="makeActive(event)">SHOPS</a>
</div>
```

This code works fine except it does not make the link class active. I have used to following javascript function to make the links active. However it does not work.

```js
function makeActive(evt) {
    var i, normal;
    normal = document.getElementsByClassName("normal");
    for (i = 0; i < normal.length; i++) {
        normal[i].className = normal[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

And this is the css code I have used to style the links when they have been activated.

```css
.sidenav a.active {
    background-color: #001F5A;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I have been trying to find what is wrong with my code, but I can't seem to find what I'm missing here. Please help! Thankyou!

Comment: Isn't the normal action, when a link get clicked, to follow that link? The `onclick` event code will be executed before the link is followed, not after it has been followed. This means that even if your code works, you won't see it for very long. (I don't understand why people downvote this question? Moreso, without even leaving a comment...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that you could do it would be to make use of the browser's `localStorage` - If you modify the above `playersidenav.php` slightly by removing the inline event handler like this and then including some Javascript within this file so that it looks like this:

```
<div class="column sidenav">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="../images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
        <h1 style="color:white;float:right;padding-top:7%">Hello John!</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="normal" href="news.php">NEWS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="schedule.php">SCHEDULE</a>
    <a class="normal" href="partners.php">PARTNERS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="coaches.php">COACHES</a>
    <a class="normal" href="tournaments.php">TOURNAMENTS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="events.php">EVENTS</a>
    <a class="normal" href="shops.php">SHOPS</a>
</div>
<script>
    //The name of the store in localStorage
    const store='LINK_ACTIVATED_MEMORY';
    
    // the class to add to indicate active state
    const cn='active';
    
    // nodelist of all sidenav links
    const links=document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav > a.normal');

    // ensure any "active" links have class removed and then 
    // save new hyperlink to localStorage
    const makeActive=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      links.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove(cn));
      localStorage.setItem( store, e.target.href );
      location.href=e.target.href;
    };
    
    // on page load run this function - check the store
    // and iterate through nodelist to match saved value and
    // node value.
    const loadActive=()=>{
        let stored=localStorage.getItem( store );
        if( stored==null )return;
        
        Array.from( links ).some(a=>{
            if( stored==a.href ){
                a.classList.add(cn)
                return true;
            }
        });
    };
    
    //bind the event handler
    links.forEach(a=>a.addEventListener('click',makeActive));
    
    // load active link class
    loadActive();
    
</script>
```

The link that is clicked will be stored in `localStorage` and then when the new page is loaded the `loadActive` function will be invoked to set the `active` class. As per the comment by @Kiko Software - the default action when clicking a hyperlink would mask any highlighting attempt anyway so the actual setting of the class should be done on page load/reload.

After thinking about the suggestion by @Kiko Software that this could be done with PHP and dispense with Javascript altogether I wrote that as an alternative solution.

The included file `playersidenav.php`:

```
<?php

    $cn='active';
    
    $links=array(
        'home.php'          =>  'TEST PAGE HOME',
        'news.php'          =>  'NEWS',
        'schedule.php'      =>  'SCHEDULE',
        'partners.php'      =>  'PARTNERS',
        'coaches.php'       =>  'COACHES',
        'tournaments.php'   =>  'TOURNAMENTS',
        'events.php'        =>  'EVENTS',
        'shops.php'         =>  'SHOPS'
    );
?>

    <div class="column sidenav">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="../images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
            <h1 style="color:white; float:right; padding-top:7%">Hello John!</h1>
        </div>
<?php
        foreach( $links as $href => $text ){
            printf(
                '<a href="%s" class="normal %s">%s</a>',
                $href,
                ( basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] )==$href ? $cn : '' ),
                $text
            );
        }
?>
    </div>
```

And an example page calling said file, called `home.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .sidenav a.active {
                background-color: #001F5A;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            a{margin:1rem;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <?php
            require sprintf('%s/playersidenav.php',__DIR__);
        ?>
        
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP include file compares the array key to the basename from the current `SCRIPT_FILENAME` server variable and adds the class accordingly and negates the need for Javascript completely. Just proves the old saying - `"There's more than one way to skin a cat"`

Comment: Yes, this is better. I'm not sure you need to use localStorage to do this. Something like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `__FILE__` could be used to find the current active script and does not depend on client-side storage.

Comment: Probably better to never use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as it has the potential to introduce malicious code but I agree it could be done with PHP and not relying upon localStorage

Comment: Yes, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` can be modified by a user, and carries a risk. See: [Cross-site Scripting (XSS) and exploiting $_SERVER[‘PHP_SELF’\]](https://www.joe0.com/2016/12/08/cross-site-scripting-xss-and-exploiting-_serverphp_self/)

Comment: Is there a way to set the active class to a default target page in the first suggested solution, when no link is clicked? (Maybe I want to make news.php active, right after a player has logged into the system.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1

```
function makeActive(evt) {
    var i, normal;
    normal = document.getElementsByClassName("normal")
    for (i = 0; i < normal.length; i++) {
        normal[i].className = "normal"
    }
    evt.target.className = "normal active"
}
```

Solution #2

```
function makeActive(evt) {
    var i, normal;
    normal = document.getElementsByClassName("normal")
    for (i = 0; i < normal.length; i++) {
      normal[i].classList.remove('active')
    }
    evt.target.classList.add("active")
}
```